# Crash at UISlider setMinimumTrackTintColor on device

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a uislider ..and custmize it.

```
 CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI*0.5);//for vertical 
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 150.0, 80);
 slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];//crash on device
  slider.transform = trans;
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 25.0;
      [self.view addSubview:slider];
```

The code works fine on simulater..
But on device it crashes at  [slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];.
.i am  using device  ios 4.3.i think custmization of uislider not working on device.
Dose anybody have an idea ..plz let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

property **MinimumTrackTintColor** is only available in iOS 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

```
[slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];//crash on device
```

the method is [available](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS (5.0 and later)